# Mac air: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, unix

I write the log under `/var/log/mysite`

```
drwxrwxr-x   6 Ariel          wheel             204B 12 25 09:42 myproject/
```

When executing python file,I got permission denied

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/myproject/django.log'
```

How can I safely set the permission to the user `Ariel` ??

Comment: Run it with `sudo`: `sudo python file.py`

Comment: Did my solution end up working for you?

Comment: Thank you for help. Finally I use ````chmod 775 /var/log/myproject```` solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your command with `sudo` for elevated privileges. Run:

```
sudo !!
```

in order to execute your previous command (that caused the error) with `sudo`.

Alternatively you can use `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python` (or `/var/log` if you wish).
If all fails (very unlikely), try `sudo chmod -R +xw /var/log/`.

Comment: I try ````sudo chown -R $USER /var/log/mysite````  But still permission denied

Comment: @user2492364 did you try to run your python with sudo !!    ? Did you try sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python      ?

Comment: Yes ````sudo xxx.py```` can work. I still want to know can I excute without sudo

Comment: @user2492364 try: sudo chmod -R +xw /var/log/ and then run your python (without sudo).

Answer (score 1):

The user of the python process need execute permission for the directories `/var`, `/var/log`, `/var/log/myproject` and write permission for the file.